# Problema al pasar una variable de una activity a un fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, navigation-drawer

tengo un proyecto en android studio con Kotlin. En el tengo un activity que tiene un Navigation Drawer, bueno lo que yo necesito es pasar una variable que tengo en esta activity (MainActivity) a un fragment de la misma. Estuve investigando y vi que la forma de enviarlo necesito crear un Bundle, bueno es lo que hice pero no logro conseguirlo porque los codigos de las guias que segui no son parecidos al mio.

Este es mi MainActivity. user es la variable que necesito pasar al fraqment

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.navigateUp
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_gallery.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration

    var user: String? = null



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        user = intent.extras?.getString("email") //variable a pasar al Fragment



        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById(R.id.fab)
        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->

            pedirYa()
        }


        val bundle = Bundle() // aqui cree un bundle
        bundle.putString("nombre", user)

        val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow), drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)



    }




    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }



    private fun pedirYa(){

            println("Main ")


            val pedirIntent = Intent(this, RestaurantesActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("email", user)

            }
            startActivity(pedirIntent)
    }

}
```

Este es mi Fragment.

```
package com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.home

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.R
import com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.RestaurantesActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*

class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    var user = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?


    ): View? {
        homeViewModel =
                ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
        homeViewModel.correol.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            textView.text = it

            pedirYa()


        })

        // aqui obtengo los datos del Bundle
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            user = getArguments()?.getString("nombre").toString();
        }




        return root
    }

    private fun pedirYa(){

        buttonPedir.setOnClickListener{

            val pedirIntent = Intent(getActivity(), RestaurantesActivity::class.java).apply {
                putExtra("mail", user)
            }
            startActivity(pedirIntent)

        }
    }
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar, como pueden ver en el codigo ya cree un bundle y en el fragment lo intento conseguir pero creo que me falta algo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estás usando el navigation component, puedes usar el método `navController.navigate()` para enviar argumentos a cualquier destination que esté declarada en tu [NavGraph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-design-graph)

```
val bundle = bundleOf("nombre" to user)
navController.navigate(R.id.destination, bundle)
```

Tu forma de recibirlo es correcta excepto que el `if (getArguments() != null)` es innecesario dado que el null check ya lo está haciendo la safe call (`?.`). Esto es totalmente seguro

```
user = getArguments()?.getString("nombre").toString()
```

Si no sabes cual es id que debes pasar como primer argumento a la función `navigate()`, puedes buscarlo en tu grafico de navegación

```
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment" <-- este es el ID
        android:name="com.ezdev.chepesdelivery.ui.home.HomeFragment" />
    ...
</navigation>
```